# How to get request user or logged user from model manager?

Tags: python, django, django-models

We have created a manager class in models.py We can not access request user.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    instructors = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), 
    ....
    
class InstructorCourseManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(instructors=request.user)

class ProxyInstructorCourse(Course):
    objects = InstructorCourseManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You should not mix the `request` object with models, do the filtering in `views`